# SQLite date BETWEEN WHERE query not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working with SQLite3 and Python and trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT id, command, username, date FROM Data WHERE tool = 'Slack' AND date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-01-01' ORDER BY date ASC;
```

There are entries that should theoretically match a row in the table. This entry should match it:

|1|Slack|.case|elynchmilner|2020-05-01|

It should match since 2020-05-01 is between 2020-01-01 and 2021-01-01. I also tried running the query in the sqlite3 console and that did not work either.

Help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Check again your data. Are the dates exactly as you think they are? Maybe there are leading spaces?

Comment: I'll check that but the strings I insert into the database don't have leading spaces. I tried date >= '2020-01-01' on its own which works but date <= '2021-01-01' doesn't work as the <= operator or < operator doesn't seem to want to work

Comment: If the dates are ok it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look tomorrow again when my head is a bit fresher 

Answer (score 0):

My fault. The issue was with the insert statement. I was inserting the following fields (tool, command, date, username), but in the values field I inserted the username and date in the wrong order so username went in for date and date went in for username.

Don't know how I didn't notice that until now!